# Codename One CheckBox with RTL

Tags: codenameone

I have set up a simple form with three checkboxes as shown below.

The problem arises when I use right to left with RTL support.

The boxes then cover the texts in a strange way.

I didn't set the alignment I have only changed the color to blue.

When I don't use RTL, checkboxes look fine!!

Also I tested on iPhone device and the same issue happens.

On Android devices, it works fine but it ignores RTL support!!

[image]

Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a regression with the `CheckBox` and the opposite side mode. Please file an issue on that. The workaround is to disable the opposite side mode either via the theme constant or:

```
cb.setOppositeSide(false);
```